# Building an Article/blog page in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have a rails project for a travel blog, now I'm wondering how to structure the blogposts. A `view` of a `post` would contain (in alternating orders) titles, paragraphs and pictures. so it wouldn't be as easy as writing the following code in my `show` view

```
<p><%= @post.body %></p>
```

But to be honest, I have no idea how to structure a `post` instance towards this result. Are there any gems that help to create articles? Or would you make a model for each `element` that is part of a `post`? Like a `post` has many `titles`, has many `paragraphs` and many `pictures`?
Any idea is welcome!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement image uploading separately (for example, using [CarrierWave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave)).

And then you just use `Markdown` ([RedCarpet gem](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet)) for your post bodies. And actually, then you *do* use `<%= @post.body %>` to render it (Post's `body` method should take Markdown from database and return rendered HTML). Markdown is that thing which is used to format StackOverflow posts.

Alternatively, you could use [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) as a Ruby-based solution for generating static blog posts (it uses Markdown for generating source as well). This way you don't even need VDS (or cloud) hosting, simple static hosting will do just fine.

Comment: Jekyll looks like a nice option but the thing is that I already made 90% of the blog site kinda want to finish that thing first rather than starting over in Jekyll ;D

That RedCarpet gem looks interesting enough though, I think it might just do what I want! Thanks!!

Comment: Everything is working perfectly, but I need to be able to mix the markdown with ruby. Kramdown is another mardown converter, which allows you to mix markdown with plain html, but doesn't recognize the ruby tags <%= %>

Anybody an idea how to be able to write ruby in my markdown?

Comment: Please think for a minute on what specifically do you want, and then ask another question. You can post link to it back here if you'd like me to see it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31994483/rails-mix-erb-tags-with-markdown

Okay, here it is