# Creating a custom block tag in liquid

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, template-engine, liquid

I'm trying to make a custom tag `{% render-slider, ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg',...] %}` that renders in to the following html code.

```
<div class="slider">
    <a href="#" class="unslider-arrow prev icon-chevron-with-circle-left"></a>
    <a href="#" class="unslider-arrow next icon-chevron-with-circle-right"></a>
    <ul>
        <% images.each do |image| %>
            <li style="background-image: url(<%= asset_path image %>);">
        <% end %>
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This will feature be used on a blog website, so that users can use this custom tag while making blogposts to generate a certain layout for their pictures where-ever they feel like in their blogpost.
I've been google-ing and reading for hours, but the documentation is just not easy enough for a beginner like me.
So far I've got this (which again could be completely wrong):

```
class FillSlider < Liquid::Block
def initialize(tag_name, images, tokens)
    super
    @images = images
end
def render(context)
    **template filled with images**
end
```

As you can see, I'm stuck at writing the render method. I know it has to be something that looks like this, but I can't put the 2 together...

```
<div class="slider">
    <a href="#" class="unslider-arrow prev icon-chevron-with-circle-left"></a>
    <a href="#" class="unslider-arrow next icon-chevron-with-circle-right"></a>
    <ul>
        {% for image in images%}
            <li style="background-image: url({{image}});">
        {% end %}
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me with it? And don't let it stop you if you have trouble with the asset_path helper, that's something we can figure out later, now I just want to get how this custom tag should be build.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, wasn't that supposed to be written by the user? If it's not used by the user, you can use plain erb there.

Comment: yes this code will be used by the user, I updated the question

Comment: @sjbuysse If using images is all you want from Liquid, I strongly suggest that instead you just upload the images separately and give the user hyperlinks for manually inserting them. Try adding images to your StackOverflow question and you will see what I mean.

Comment: That's not a bad idea, I might just give that a try. Thank's a lot EugZol